# How to extract parameters from glm.nb() and generate random numbers from that distribution in R

Tags: r

I am first fitting a negative binomial on my data

```
fit<-glm.nb(E ~ R, data=df2)
```

Format of E , R data in df2 is like

R is basically integers from 1 to 70 and E is decimal numbers .
Now I want to generate say 100 random numbers from the negative binomial fit that I got on this data . How do I get it using rnbinom

Presently I am using

```
rnbinom(100,mu=mean(df2$E), size=fit$theta)
```

but when I plot the density function by

```
xseq<-seq(1,70,1)
densities<-dnbinom(xseq, mu=mean(df2$E),size=fit$theta)
plot(xseq,densities,col="darkgreen",xlab="",ylab="Density",type="l",lwd=2, cex=2, main="PDF of Negative Binomial")
```

I am getting a plot looking nothing like my data , but when I use

```
predict(fit, newdata=data.frame(R=5), type="response")
```

and keep giving different integer values of R from 1 to 70 I guess I get a better curve .

```
xseq<-seq(1,70,1)
plot(predict(fit, newdata=data.frame(R=xseq), type="response"))
```

What am I missing , I somehow need to generate 100 random numbers from the negative binomial distribution that fits my data .
THIS IS WHAT I GOT FROM DENSITIES
  [image]
THIS IS WHAT I GOT FROM PREDICT
[image]

MY data is more like the predict curve

Comment: So E does not consist of counts?

Comment: E contains real values like 2.5 , 2.7 like these , R contains integers from 1 to 70 ; NOTE -> I am not saying negative binomial will be a good fit , I just want the best fitting negative binomial function parameters with which I can generate random numbers

Comment: Why not provide a minimal working example?

Comment: See if the graphs I gave do help you , I want to post the dataframe of E and R values but the values are getting haphazard

Comment: The bottom plot is the expectation function over the range of R and the top plot is of a density at the sample mean. They appear consistent.